# Change behaviour of rendering in MathJax

Tags: javascript, mathjax

Where can I change behaviour of MathJax in rendering formulas?
I need two cases:

1. Don't show formulas until all formulas are parsed.
2. Show formula as soon as it is processed by MathJax

Answer (score 2, accepted):

MathJax offers configuration options to modify *equation chunking*. To quote the documentation

> EqnChunk: 50
>
> EqnChunkFactor: 1.5
>
> EqnChunkDelay: 100
>
> These values control how “chunky” the display of mathematical expressions will be; that is, how often the equations will be updated as they are processed.
>
> EqnChunk is the number of equations that will be typeset before they appear on screen. Larger values make for less visual flicker as the equations are drawn, but also mean longer delays before the reader sees anything.
>
> EqChunkFactor is the factor by which the EqnChunk will grow after each chunk is displayed.
>
> EqChunkDelay is the time (in milliseconds) to delay between chunks (to allow the browser to respond to other user interaction).
>
> Set EqnChunk to 1, EqnChunkFactor to 1, and EqnChunkDelay to 10 to get the behavior from MathJax v1.1 and below.

These settings can be set for HTML and SVG output separately. See the docs: [HTML-output](http://docs.mathjax.org/en/latest/options/HTML-CSS.html),  [SVG output](http://docs.mathjax.org/en/latest/options/SVG.html).

Edit

As Davide Cervone commented below, set EqnChunk to a large number (larger than the number of equations on the page) to get your request (1), and set EqnChunk and EqnChunkFactor both to 1 to get your request (2).

Comment: So just to be explicit, set `EqnChunk` to a large number (larger than the number of equations on the page) to get your request (1), and set `EqnChunk` and `EqnChunkFactor` both to 1 to get your request (2).

Comment: Thanks, @DavideCervone, I've added your comment to the answer.

Comment: @PeterKrautzberger Thanks for excellent answer. Can you help me more. I need to make formula hidden until it is ready to be rendered. I know how to set event in queue, but this works only after all formulas are typesetted. What should I write to hook event of typesetting after each formula?

Comment: I saw your new question. Seems like you found a solution. If you don't want MathJax to do its initial typesetting run, you have to set `skipStartupTypeset: true` -- see http://docs.mathjax.org/en/latest/options/hub.html